# Mobile functionality of keyframe animations and transitions

Tags: css

I have been working on my personal website for about 2 weeks now, and I have come to the stage of adding animations for when you scroll and when the website starts. However, it was all going well until I checked my phone (IPhone XR) and noticed that none of the animations are smooth. If you wanted to check it out yourself, here is the link to my website: https://burton-jong.vercel.app/ (Please let me know if this link does not work). Here are some examples of my code, for example the loader at the start of the app:

```
@keyframes wheel {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 40%, white);
  animation: wheel 2s linear infinite;
}
.loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 40%, white);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  z-index: 1;
  filter: blur(30px);
}
```

as well as the animations of the text that should be smooth:

```
@keyframes fade-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px) scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  }
}

.animate {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.slow-3 {
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
}
```

I have already tried to look around to see if there was a solution, but there is nothing specific to what I am experiencing. I also have another question that is somewhat related, but I was wondering if I should also include -webkit animations into my css for browser compatibility? To be honest, I am not sure what they do as I am still somewhat new to all this. Thanks for reading and I will try my best to answer any other questions as soon as possible.

Comment: Please put just enough code into your question to make a runnable snippet. The external site will shortly be useless to future readers as it gets debugged.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example